# Prevent gnu screen from resizing display size

Tags: gnu-screen

Every time I start screen (screen -A) or try to connect to an already running screen session (screen -Ax) my terminal is resized to 80 columns. I want to prevent screen from resizing my terminal.

I am using iTerm on Snow Leopard and my screen sessions are on a centos machine (I use bash as my shell).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try adding this (from `/etc/screenrc`) to your `~/.screenrc`:

```
# Change the xterm initialization string from is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>
# (This fixes the "Aborted because of window size change" konsole symptoms found
#  in bug #134198)
termcapinfo xterm* 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'
```

You may need to change the "xterm" to match your `$TERM`.

The `termcapinfo` line sets `is` (ininitialization string) for any terminal with a name starting with "xterm" to a sequence of escape codes. `\E` represents `escape` and the codes are as follows:

```
\E[r       - set scrolling region to default (full size of window)
\E[m       - reset all resources (keyboard) to their initial values
\E[2J      - Erase in Display (ED). 2 -> Erase All.
\E[H       - set cursor position to default (1, 1)
\E[?7h     - DEC Private Mode Set. 7 -> Wraparound Mode
\E[?1;4;6l - DEC Private Mode Reset. 1 -> Normal Cursor Keys; 4  -> Jump (Fast) Scroll; 6 -> Normal Cursor Mode
```

The replaced line had these codes:

```
\E[!p      - Soft terminal reset
\E[?3;4l   - DEC Private Mode Reset. 3 -> 80 Column Mode; 4 -> Jump (Fast) Scroll
\E[4l      - Reset Mode. 4 -> Replace Mode
\E>        - Normal keypad
```

(source: [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html))

Comment: thanks! added this answer to http://serverfault.com/questions/158508/terminal-width-issues-with-linux-screen/499008#499008

Comment: Would you mind decoding the termcapinfo line?

Comment: @Huckle: I added an explanation of the escape codes.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation (and suggested equivalents) for the xterm initialization string aren't completely accurate.

Starting with the string from xterm's terminal description:

```
is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>
```

we have

```
CSI ! p   Soft terminal reset (DECSTR).
CSI ? Pm l
      DEC Private Mode Reset (DECRST).
...
        Ps = 3  -> 80 Column Mode (DECCOLM).
        Ps = 4  -> Jump (Fast) Scroll (DECSCLM).
CSI Pm l  Reset Mode (RM).
...
        Ps = 4  -> Replace Mode (IRM).
ESC >     Normal Keypad (DECKPNM).
```

But **`DECSTR`** resets several things not found in the replacement:

- the cursor shape and appearance
- character sets
- other keyboard modes related to application/normal modes (**`DECCKM`**, **`KAM`**, **`DECKPAM`**)
- wraparound (and reverse wraparound)
- origin mode

Also, it doesn't clear the screen.

The reason for using **`DECSTR`** ([since 1997](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_34)) is to keep *termcap* sizes small enough to fit in termcap's 1024-byte limit.

The setting for `screen` is from the Debian package; the bug report mentioned in the comment is *[Debian  #134198 —
screen: has some sort of odd emulation problem most noticable with irssi and konsole](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=134198)*, from 2002.  `screen` does not recognize that sequence, and incidentally, KDE konsole does not implement that sequence, as seen in [KDE #134892](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134892), while at the same time its developers state in [KDE #145977](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145977) that they prefer to not use a different `TERM` value than `xterm`.  Since some users might want a terminal description which does match konsole's capabilities, that's in ncurses as `konsole`, e.g.,

```
is2=\E[m\E[?7h\E[4l\E>\E7\E[r\E[?1;3;4;6l\E8
```

versus

```
is2=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l
```

Removing the spurious clear-screen, the relevant portion of screen's customization is

```
is2=\E[r\E[m\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l
```

so what was left out was (aside from `DECCOLM`) `\E[4l`.

The `\E7` and `\E8` in the initialization string save/restore the cursor position when adjusting the scrolling margins.  Just like the insert-mode, some users would notice the absence of the feature.

The point of the customization is to suppress the **`DECCOLM`** (80/132 column) switching, and working from screen's cut-down and rather old customization might not work as well as adapting from a terminal description written *for* the terminal.

Further reading:

- [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)
- [VT220 Programmer Reference Manual](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/)