# Set terminal width in screen using PuTTY connection

Tags: putty, gnu-screen

I'm connecting from PuTTY on a Windows box to a RHEL server. I like to do my work in screen, and I like a terminal window that's wider than 80 characters.

I have my PuTTY terminal set to be 120 characters wide.

When I start screen, it changes the terminal width to 80 characters.

When I do CTRL-A, W, I get, "Your termcap does not specify how to change the terminal's width to 132."

I figured this would be a reasonably quick fix with a Google search, but it turns out that I haven't been able to find the answer.

Can anyone help me configure things so that gnu-screen will use a width other than 80 characters in PuTTY?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it in Putty, but have a look at https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/ it's much nicer to work with

Comment: Show output of `TERM`: `echo $TERM`.

Comment: Does "C-A F" work?  This runs the "fit" command which may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL defined some DEC Private Mode Reset (DECRST) sequence in the xterm initialisation and reset terminal controls switching the terminal [80 Column Mode (DECCOLM), VT100](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_). You can verivy if they are there by command: `infocmp | grep '\\E\[?[0-9;]*3;[0-9;]*l'` Unfortunately screen is using either is2 or rs2 to prepare the display. I found a solution for this issue on StackExchange SuperUser here: [Prevent gnu screen from resizing display size](https://superuser.com/questions/217066/prevent-gnu-screen-from-resizing-display-size)